How I can periodically forward an specific message to a chat with a BOT in Telegram?
I have to send a fix message to a BOT periodically (every 15 minutes). As best of my knowledge, I should make a BOT to do this. Also as I know, a BOT cannot send any message to another BOT in Telegram. So, I decided to forward a fix message from a chat to the chat with destination BOT.
I found that I should make a new BOT and write a piece of code. Also, I found the required piece of code as bellow but it needs source chat ID, destination chat ID and message_id which I don't know how I can find them. I used a BOT with username @get_id_bot but it give me user IDs not chat IDs. Please help me to do the task.
Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.
var telegramToken = 'YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN';
var sourceChatId = 'SOURCE_CHAT_ID'; // The chat ID from where messages will be forwarded
var destinationChatId = 'DESTINATION_CHAT_ID'; // The chat ID of the bot to which messages will be forwarded

function forwardMessageToBot(messageId) {
var url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + telegramToken + '/forwardMessage';
var payload = {
'chat_id': destinationChatId,
'from_chat_id': sourceChatId,
'message_id': messageId
};

// Use UrlFetchApp to forward the message to the Telegram Bot
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
'method': 'post',
'contentType': 'application/json',
'payload': JSON.stringify(payload)
});
}

function createTrigger() {
// Delete existing triggers to avoid duplicates
var existingTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < existingTriggers.length; i++) {
if (existingTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction() === 'forwardMessageToBot') {
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(existingTriggers[i]);
}
}

// Create a new time-driven trigger that runs at the desired interval
ScriptApp.newTrigger('forwardMessageToBot')
.timeBased()
.everyMinutes(15) // Set the frequency here (15 minutes in this case)
.create();
}

// This function should be called with the specific message ID you want to forward
function setupForwardingForMessage(messageId) {
forwardMessageToBot(messageId);
createTrigger();
}

